SharePoint Online Modern Page Search Refinement Webpart not Available
In SharePoint online modern page search related or Search Refiner webpart not available. But it is available in classic page of the same site. I enabled the Allow 'Custom scripts' options from the admin center and Enabled Server Related features both in Manage site features and Site collection features. What could be the reason for it not showing in modern page's webpart section?

The reason the Search Refiner webpart is not available in the modern page's webpart section is that classic search webparts are not supported in modern SharePoint pages. Modern SharePoint pages use a different set of webparts designed to be more streamlined and user-friendly.
As a workaround, you can use the PnP Modern Search webpart, which provides similar functionality and can be customized to include search refiners and other features.
You will get more details here.
